# Creating a Batch file that Creates another batch file and modifies it based on another file contents

Tags: file, batch-file, mapping

Sorry for the terrible title, wanted to include as much information as possible.

Currently we are having a bit of trouble moving from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Right now we are not using any roaming profiles in Windows 10 but after each logoff, it saves a mapped_drives.txt file to a network drive for the person for reference.

Currently it contains for example something like this

```
F:,\\CHHFSV01\CORPSEC
G:,\\CHHFSV01\LAWDATA
O:,\\CEPFALI11\OCCAPPS
T:,\\CEPGCL131\APPS
```

I would like to create a batch file that would read that mapped_drives.txt file in the same directory and create a new mappings.bat file that would take the information in the mapped_drives.txt file and basically output a batch file that would map the drives if ran like below.

```
NET USE F: /D
NET USE G: /D
NET USE O: /D
NET USE T: /D

NET USE F: \\CHHFSV01\CORPSEC /P:Y
NET USE G: \\CHHFSV01\LAWDATA /P:Y
NET USE O: \\CEPFALI11\OCCAPPS /P:Y
NET USE T: \\CEPGCL131\APPS /P:Y
```

I searched and could not really find out how I can do this or if it is even possible. Any ideas from you guys/girls who are obviously much smarter than I am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to manage with something as simple as this:

```bat
@For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims=," %%A In ("mapped_drives.txt"
) Do @Net Use %%A /D && @Net Use %%A %%B /P:Y
```

When run, *(probably at login)*,it should read the `mapped_drives.txt` delete any existing mappings for those drive letters and create those defined in your text file.

**Edit**

Try this modification for the scenario mentioned in your comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
(   Echo=@Echo Off
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=," %%A In ("mapped_drives.txt"
    ) Do Echo=Net Use %%A /D
    Echo=
    For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims=," %%B In ("mapped_drives.txt"
    ) Do Echo=Net Use %%B %%C /P:Y
)>"NewMappings.cmd"
```

*This should create a batch file, `NewMappings.cmd` matching that mentioned in your question.*

Comment: Hmmm, I will check it out, to be honest I would need a new batch file as we normally get users to run the batch files themselves. But that helps a lot, Ill try it out.

Comment: Don't let them run the batch file, add that one as a scheduled task!

Comment: Looks like it does not work. EDIT: Ok it does work, but ONLY if there is a current drive at the letter, if not it just fails, anyway to make it run the command even if there is no current drive to delete?

Comment: Yeah there are tons of stuff we should be doing but this is how people way above me want stuff done :( Trust me it is annoying.

Comment: See if the **Edit** helps!

Comment: Thanks Compo, the edit did not work however. I appreciate the help

Comment: I've re-wrote it so that it outputs to a new batch file now, _according to your comments_.

Comment: Thanks Compo. I tried the newest one (The write file one) and it does not seem to create the file.

Comment: It has been tested and works perfectly, you must have failed to follow your own criteria. My posted batch script, let's call it `CreateMaps.cmd` and `mapped_drives.txt` should be in the same location, when you double click on it, you'll get the new `NewMappings.cmd` file in that same location.

Comment: You are 100% correct. For some reason It was not working when I had it saved on my desktop, once I moved it to another folder it works perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmmm, so something weird is going on. It only works if I put the two files on a local folder, if I send the files to someone else the batch file does not work, if I run the files on a network drive with full admin it does not work, not sure what is going on :(

Comment: What happens when you add a new second line: `PushD "%~dp0"` and a new last line `PopD`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to create another batch file, as you could simply use one, but as per your requirement, this should check for the drive letter, if it exists, it will write the delete mapping function and create mapping function of drives to a new batch file, but obviously, it will only create it if it existed.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (mapped_drives.txt) do (
   if exist %%a echo net use %%a /d
   echo net use %%a %%b /P:Y
) > %~dp0map_now.cmd
```

If however you want to delete it if exist, and create it even if it did **not** exist, then this should do.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (mapped_drives.txt) do (
   if exist %%a (
   echo net use %%a /d
  )
   echo net use %%a %%b /P:Y
) > %~dp0map_now.cmd
```

Comment: Let me give that one a try. The reason why I want it to create a new one is the way it is setup here we want to grab that mapped_drives.txt file, save it locally, run the batch file to create a new batch file that we would copy back to the users network drive. For some reason for Windows 10 they are not allowing users to have roaming profiles and want us to get them to run batch files :( So no registry editing which would be so much easier.

Comment: I gave it a try and it did not create the file. I put the following in mapped_drives.txt and it did not create a output file. It would save the output file in the same dir correct?
T:,\\CEPGCL131\APPS

Comment: Ok, after reading reply from compo below i moved the files to another folder and it now works perfect, thanks so much.

Comment: @supeg yes, it should create the file map_now.cmd in the same directory. It could however be that windows 7 is writing to `C:\windows\system32` so I have edited the pipe method so you can test again.

Comment: Its weird, If I run the batch file via explorer or directory opus it does not work, if I run it from a command prompt it works...

Comment: @supeg did you try the edited code? anyway, does not really matter now, you got a solution already :)